# jQuery change button text doesn't work correct

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a button with jQuery Design.

I want to change the text if anyone click on the button with this code

```
$("#change_button").html('abort');
```

On clicking button the design changed.

Before

[image]

after

[image]

give it a way to change the text without change the design ?

Comment: Please show us the button html too!

Comment: <button type="button" id="change_button">Change</button>

Comment: add all relevant code to OP

Comment: this is all relevant code

Comment: Can you create a snippet or jsfiddle showing us the problem? Because there seems to be something else wrong. It is hard to say now what's the correct answer.

Comment: This is happening because the width of button is not fixed

Comment: show you html button it is not included in OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your button width to some fix value like:

```
<button type="button" style="width:80px;" id="change_button">Change</button>
```

JS:

```
$("#change_button").click(function(){
        $(this).html('Abort');
    });
```

It will work

Comment: He will downvote this because he doesn't know what he's doing. LMAO!

Comment: @wiifree Are you sure this will work in input? Get you facts straight! You rather use .value or .val() when changing value in input. LMAO. And you don't like px. Then use of em, vw, vh, etc. Try to learn native js. So that, you can easily learn jQuery and other js frameworks.

Comment: I have just consider the current scenario, and it is satisfied with .html(). For input it is .val().

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#change_button").click(function(){
        $(this).text("Hello world!");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="change_button">Here is your data</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<input type='button' value='Add' id='change_button'>
$("#change_button").attr('value', 'Save'); //versions older than 1.6

<input type='button' value='Add' id='change_button'>
$("#change_button").prop('value', 'Save'); //versions newer than 1.6
```